# Docker container exits immediately on `docker start`

Tags: docker, arm, ros, amd-processor

I'm trying to start a docker container with `docker start my_container`, but it is exiting immediately. It works fine on some machines, but not on others. Here's my process:

1. Pull an image via `docker pull <repo>:latest`
2. Create a container via `docker create --name my_container <repo>:latest`
3. Start the container via `docker start my_container`

When I check the running docker processes via `docker ps -a`, I see that the status of `my_container` is `Exited (1) 2 seconds ago`.

When I run `docker logs my_container`, the only output is:

```
standard_init_linux.go:190: exec user process caused "exec format error"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The underlying issue in my case was an architecture mismatch.

My `Dockerfile` was using an `amd64` base image. I built an image from this dockerfile and pushed it to a remote repository. I then pulled the image onto a device with `arm32v7` architecture, created a container from the image, and tried to run the container.

---

A docker image built from the base image below will work on `amd64` - it will not work on `arm32v7`.

```
FROM amd64/ros:kinetic-ros-core-xenial
```

A docker image built from the base image below will work on `arm32v7` - it will not work on `amd64`.

```
FROM arm32v7/ros:kinetic-ros-core-xenial
```

A docker image built from a `Dockerfile` with the base image defined as below will default to the architecture of your current machine.

```
FROM ros:kinetic-ros-core-xenial
```